# Access Violation with uninitialized variable being passed to method call that initializes it

Tags: c++, unicode, c++builder, access-violation, c++builder-10.3-rio

I need some theoretical explanation of the following memory access violation BEFORE even entering the method:

```cpp
String testMethod (AnsiString param1);
AnsiString A1 = testMethod(A1);
```

I am trying to understand the theory behind the problem.

`A1` is getting initialized by the return value of `testMethod()` while at the same time it is passed to `testMethod()`. What happens before the method is actually entered? When passed to `testMethod()` it has no actual value/a random value, has it? A local copy of `A1` is created, does the exception occur during that process, actually?

Trying to debug, a lot of `AnsiString`, `UnicodeString`, and `AnsiStringBase` methods are entered.

Why does it work, when I change the method signature this way:

```cpp
AnsiString testMethod (AnsiString param1);
```

Comment: What are `AnsiString` and `String`? Classes, typedefs, or something else? There are several things that could be going on here but the exact problem depends on the specific types involved.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm [`AnsiString`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AnsiString) and [`UnicodeString`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString) are string classes in C++Builder's RTL. `String` is just a typedef for `UnicodeString`.

Comment: If the compiler can detect that the code is nonsense (i.e. testing for `this` being a `nullptr`, or passing an uninitialized variable to a function and returning it), the compiler is free to do anything with the code.  See the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

Comment: This is a good piece of information as well, thanks @PaulMcKenzie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AnsiString A1 = testMethod(A1);`

When you reach this point:
`AnsiString A1` 
the name `A1` exists and is known to the compiler.  Thus, you can use it farther to the right.  However, you are calling `testMethod` with a raw memory block that has not been constructed yet.  That's going to blow up when it hits the copy constructor which tries to read the members inside `A1`.

Here is an elaboration:  Although it's all written on one line, you have several steps going on and things handled at different times.

At compilation time, a group of bytes are set aside and the label `A1` used to refer to them.

At run time, a statement is executed to initialize `A1`.  This works by calling a constructor which is designed to expect raw memory and is responsible for making that memory into a legal instance of that type.

However, in this case, obtaining the value to use to initialize this variable it uses the function call which passes `A1` as a parameter.  But `A1` has not been initialized yet.

At another level of detail, the code is realized the following way:  A function returning a class type is implemented by passing the address of the result area as another argument.  The definition of `A1` caused the compiler to set aside memory for that, but nothing has been done with it yet.  At this point in the execution, it calls a function `__impl_testMethod(&A1, copy_of(A1));`.

> Trying to debug, a lot of AnsiString, UnicodeString, and AnsiStringBase methods are entered.

You are seeing the copy constructor in action.  You probably really wanted to define it as:

`String testFunction (const AnsiString& param1);`
because there is no reason to **duplicate** the object into `param1` if that function will be looking at it but not modifying its own private copy.

And, C++ does not have "methods" but rather member functions, and this isn't even a member function anyway (as far as I can see in your OP).  It is properly described as a "free function".

Comment: This is the kind of answer I hoped for, but didn't expect to get, thanks a lot. Still, there's one point I would like to get clarified: Isn't the copy constructor called to create a local copy of A1 for the method (copy_of(A1)) and fails at this place, instead of the copy constructor to set A1 to the value of the member function? The function hasn't got entered, yet, so it has to be the local copy one, right? And with &A1 you did probably mean some other variable reserved to hold the address of the return value I guess.

Comment: Passing `A1` **by value** to `testMethod()` will attempt to create a *copy* of `A1` into a temporary object, thus invoking `AnsiString`'s copy constructor with `A1` as the source object to be copied, before `testMethod()` is then entered. But `A1` is not a valid object yet, so creating that temporary copy is Undefined Behavior. Your crash is *likely* in the creation of that temporary, but it *could* also be when using `param1` for any purpose inside the function (assigning the return value, perhaps?). Only the debugger can tell you for sure exactly where the crash is really happening.

Comment: Great, thanks Remy, this is the last piece of information I was missing. Thus, it has happened due to the first case, because during debugging I was able to see that the method hasn't been entered, yet.

Comment: By `copy_of_(A1)` I mean that it will invoke the copy constructor on A1 and it's the resulting copy that's passed to `testMethod`.  The result of `testMethod` is constructed directly into the memory that's named `A1`, described in the standard that way as of C++17, and what actually takes place after optimizations in earlier compilers.

Comment: @kvirk have you tried using [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/)?

Comment: @JDługosz Thanks for the explanation. I've never heard of the Compiler Explorer before, thanks for the link, I like the live assembly representation.

Answer (score 1):

`AnsiString A1 = testMethod(A1);` is simply *undefined behavior*, whether `testMethod()` returns `String` or `AnsiString`. There is no reasoning why it crashes one way but not the other.  Just don't do it, period!  You are trying to pass a *copy* of `A1` to `testMethod()` before `A1` has been constructed yet.

Comment: Thanks, I do know, this is not the way to go, but it did occur due to some string replace action, and I am that kind of person that tries to understand why things do happen, and it is just not enough to me to put it aside in the UB record. Things like these are a good chance to understand the internal workings, at least I try.

Comment: Again, don't try to make sense of what the compiler is doing when invoking *Undefined Behavior*, it can literally do whatever it wants. You can't rely on the result of UB, and this code is absolutely UB, plain and simple.

Comment: Got it, so no need to puzzle over the reason, why it did work with the AnsiString return value.